# Java compiler error variable is already defined

Tags: java

I am new to programming and am having difficulty figuring this error out:

```
C:....>javac Power.java
Power.java:12: error: variable i is already defined in method main(String[])
    `for(int **i** = 0; i < upper_limit + 1; i++)`
```

Here is the entire program. I'm sure the answer is super simple but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Power {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Scanner input_scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Powers of 2 up to? ");
        int upper_limit = input_scanner.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < upper_limit + 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " - " + Math.pow(2, i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything? The error **literally tells you what's wrong with your code**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The `i` variable is already defined as part of the `for` loop.** Just remove the following line:

```
int i = 0;
```

Comment: Damn I feel pretty stupid. Thanks for quick reply and for your help, much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < upper_limit + 1 ; i++ )
{
```

remove the int inside the for loop or the remove the line above the for loop. now you define int i twice

Answer (score 0):

you define the variable i twice in your code. It should only be defined on time. I have highlighted the two times below.

```
Scanner input_scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
System.out.print( "Powers of 2 up to? " );
int upper_limit = input_scanner.nextInt();
int i = 0;  //First time i is defined
for(int i = 0; i < upper_limit + 1 ; i++ ) //second time i is defined
{
    System.out.println( i + " - " + Math.pow( 2, i));
}
```

To fix this either remove one of the `int i = 0` lines. Both options shown below:

```
int upper_limit = input_scanner.nextInt();
//First definition removed
for(int i = 0; i < upper_limit + 1 ; i++ ) //second time i is defined
{
    System.out.println( i + " - " + Math.pow( 2, i));
}
```

second solution

```
int upper_limit = input_scanner.nextInt();
int i = 0;  //First time i is defined
for(; i < upper_limit + 1 ; i++ ) //second definition removed
{
    System.out.println( i + " - " + Math.pow( 2, i));
}
```

Comment: While correct, I guess I feel including the entire source three times is more space than it's worth.

Comment: @DaveNewton I tried to include the context, so that the asker could figure out exactly where in the code the problem occurs, as well as how the solutions look in context. That being said, I could certainly make that more concise. Edited a bit to make it shorter.